# faceDetection EmguCV

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I having a problem on given green rectangle on the picture.jpg when the picture with 5 people in there. I'm using emguCV v2.2
here the code for the button when i click and fire it.

```
Image InputImg = Image.FromFile(@"C:\img\Picture.jpg"); 
Image<Bgr,byte> ImageFrame = new Image<Bgr,byte>(new Bitmap(InputImg));

Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = ImageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
 var faces =  grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1.4, 4,
                                    HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                    new Size(25, 25))[0];
foreach (var face in faces)
            {
                ImageFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
            }
CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;
```

I expected it should return me the picture.jpg with green rectangle on each faces. But it doesn't . May i know why? is any mistake here?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the foreach has at least one rectangle maybe there are no detected faces.

Comment: Your code seems fine.  However I would suggest trying with a scaling factor of 1.1 rather than 1.4 - This value controls how much the sliding window is scaled on each facial scan; 1.1 would inflate the window by a factor of 10% rather than 40%

Comment: this is 25,25 is the size that system going to detect? If my picture size is more than is not working?  HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,new Size(25, 25)

Comment: That parameter is the minimum expected area in pixels for a face. You could view it as the "starting size" of the sliding window that is scanning your image.  So with a MinSize of 25,25  and a factor of 1.1 the process will start scanning with a 25x25 pixel window. This wil be grown to 28x28 on next iteration, then to 30x30 and so on. If a face-like image (or whatever type of image the detector has been trained for) is detected at any of these scales, it should be added to your results.

Comment: Which cascade file are you using to initialize your Haar detector?

Comment: IM using the  haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml.

Comment: You are getting only the first element of the array returned back from DetectHaarCascade method. You will have only one faces...

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>  var faces =  grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1.4, 4,
>                                     HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
>                                     new Size(25, 25))[0];
> ```

You are using `scaleFactors = 1.4` and `minNeighbors = 4`,
may be you can adjust these parameters and check the result (`scaleFactors = 1.2`?)

To prove that your haarcascade is working well, may be you can try to using webcam capture as your picture source?

```
Private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //capture webcam
        Capture grabber = new Capture();
        //test capture frame
        grabber.QueryFrame();
        //trigger event when application is idle
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Capture fail to start");
    }
}

void FrameGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image<Bgr,byte> ImageFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320,240,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
    Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = ImageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
    MCvAvgComp[] faces =  grayframe.DetectHaarCascade(haar, 1.4, 4,
                                    HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                                    new Size(25, 25))[0];
    foreach (MCvAvgComp face in faces)
    {
        ImageFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 3);
    }
    CamImageBox.Image = ImageFrame;
}
```

By the way, return type of `grayframe.DetectHaarCascade` is `MCvAvgComp[][]`,
therefore type of faces in your case is  `MCvAvgComp[]`.

Answer (score 0):

The `ScaleFactor` should be `>1.0 but closer to 1` so you may use 1.04 or 1.01 to have better results, but it will make the process slower. You may increase the `minNeighbours` so you ma have lesser false positive.
And finally use the `maxSize` parameter to limit the maximum size of the detected box. you may follow the definition of the method

```
public Rectangle[] DetectMultiScale(
    IInputArray image,
    double scaleFactor = 1.1,
    int minNeighbors = 3,
    Size minSize = null,
    Size maxSize = null
)
```